# Python tkinter create buttons with loop and edit their parameters

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I'm making a program with Tkinter where I'd need to use a "for i in range" loop, in order to create 81 Text Widgets named like :

Text1
Text2
Text3
...

and dispose them in a square (actually to make a grill for a sudoku game of a 9*9 size). After I created these 81 Text Widgets I need to place them (using .place() ) and entering their **position parameters**.
After this, I will need to collect the values that the user entered in these Text Widgets.

I'm a newbie and I don't really know how to code this.
Here is my actual code but the problem is I can't modify the parameters once the dictionnary is created and i don't know how to access to the Text Widgets parameters. Maybe using a dictionnary is not the appropriate solution to do what I want.

```
d = {}
Ypos = 100

for i in range(9):        
        Xpos = 100
    for j in range(9):            
        d["Text{0}".format(i)]= Text(window, height=1, width=1,relief = FLAT,font=("Calibri",16))
        d["Text{0}".format(i)].place(x = Xpos+,y = Ypos)
        Xpos += 35
    yPos += 35
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Modifying the parameters is not amongst your requirements. Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a complex key for the dictionary, it makes the code more complex without adding any benefit.

Since you're creating a grid, use `row` and `column` rather than `i` and `j`. This will make your code easier to understand. Also, don't use place if you're creating a grid. Tkinter has a geometry manager specifically for creating a grid.

Since you're creating a text widget with a height of one line, it makes more sense to use an entry widget.

Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root  = tk.Tk()
d = {}

window = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief="groove")
window.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for row in range(9):
    for column in range(9):
        entry = tk.Entry(window, width=1, relief="flat", font=("Calibri",16))
        entry.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew")
        d[(row,column)] = entry

root.mainloop()
```

Whenever you need to access the data in a cell, you can use the row and column easily:

```
value = d[(3,4)].get()
print("row 3, column 4 = %s" % value)
```

Comment: Thank you, your help was very useful to me !